# Socket IO V0.7: How to send message to more that one specific client

Tags: javascript, node.js, real-time, websocket, socket.io

In version 0.6 I used this method to send a message to specific group of clients. It will exclude the clients with the session IDs in the 'excludedClients' array and send to all clients who are not excluded.

```
var excludedClients = [sessionID1, sessionID2, sessionID3];
io.broadcast(msg, excludedClients);
```

1. **Is this method still applicable in V0.7?**
2. **Is this the best way of doing this?**

Hope someone can give me a hand with this, there doesn't seem to be any solid documentation for Socket IO anywhere, only briefly explained examples on the [github](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/) page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I believe so; check out the [wiki page on 0.6 to 0.7 migration](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Migrating-0.6-to-0.7).
2. If your clients can be grouped logically, you can use rooms.

> ### Rooms
>
> Sometimes you want to put a bunch of sockets in one room, and send a message to them. You can leverage rooms by calling `join` on a socket, and then with the flags `to` and `in`:
>
> ```
> io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
>   socket.join('a room');
>   socket.broadcast.to('a room').send('im here');
>   io.sockets.in('some other room').emit('hi');
> });
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I am planning on using the rooms feature already. I was needing the ability to send messages to individual clients by stating their sessionID only. 90% of the time this will be one on one iteraction between clients but it could involve up to 10 people on some occassions.

Comment: Gotcha. Just in case you weren't aware, you can use the session ID to send data to a specific client: `io.sockets.socket(sess_id).send('my message')`, et al. (see the bottom of the wiki page I linked to). Don't think you can use this to send to multiple clients, but you could loop over an array without too much hassle.